# How to catch/send XML doc with various sub arrays?

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, web-services

I am working with some web services and I ran into some puzzle that I cannot resolve. I am working with arrays of objects within an array of another object within an array of a main object.

I am using various objects like this:

> public class OBJECT1
>
> {
>
> public string item1;
>
> public string item2;
>
> public string item3;
>
> }
>
> public class OBJECT2
>
> {
>
> public string item1;
>
> public string item2;
>
> public OBJECT1[] item3;
>
> }
>
> public class OBJECT3
>
> {
>
> public string item1;
>
> public string item2;
>
> public OBJECT2[] item3;
>
> }

So my puzzle comes when I consult a database based on one element within one of the 3 objects.

Let me explain:

When I search one element from OBJECT1, I can get 1 or more items from the other objects. The question is: how can I put all the information within a table or an XML doc or a dataset? I really do not have any clue to where to start, since I want to make a structre like this:

> Object3[N]
>
> item1
>
> item2
>
> Object2[1] 
>         ítem1
>         item2
>
> ```
>  Object1[1]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[2]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[3]
>      .
>      .  
>      .
>   Object1[N]
> ```
>
> Object2[2] 
>         ítem1
>         item2
>
> ```
>  Object1[1]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[2]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[3]
>      .
>      .  
>      .
>   Object1[N]
> ```
>
> Object2[3] 
>         ítem1
>         item2
>
> ```
>  Object1[1]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[2]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[3]
>      .
>      .  
>      .
>   Object1[N]
> ```
>
> .
>      .
>      .
>      Object2[N] 
>         ítem1
>         item2
>
> ```
>  Object1[1]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[2]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[3]
>      .
>      .  
>      .
>   Object1[N]
> ```
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> Object3[N]
>
> item1
>
> item2
>
> Object2[1] 
>         ítem1
>         item2
>
> ```
>  Object1[1]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[2]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[3]
>      .
>      .  
>      .
>   Object1[N]
> ```
>
> Object2[2] 
>         ítem1
>         item2
>
> ```
>  Object1[1]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[2]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[3]
>      .
>      .  
>      .
>   Object1[N]
> ```
>
> Object2[3] 
>         ítem1
>         item2
>
> ```
>  Object1[1]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[2]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[3]
>      .
>      .  
>      .
>   Object1[N]
> ```
>
> .
>      .
>      .
>      Object2[N] 
>         ítem1
>         item2
>
> ```
>  Object1[1]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[2]
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
>   Object1[3]
>      .
>      .  
>      .
>   Object1[N]
> ```

I really do not know where to start catching this. I already got the structure, but I need a hint as to where to start. I hope you guys can help me.

I am working with Visual Studio 2008 C# and SQL Server and web services.

I hope anyone can help me with this, thanks anyway.

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) functionality to turn your object graph into an XML document with the nesting that you mentioned.

Two parts:

1. Annotate your classes with the appropriate attributes.

   ```
   [DataContract(Namespace = "DataContracts")]
   public class Foo
   {
       [DataMember]
       public string First;

       [DataMember]
       public string Second;

       [DataMember]
       public string Third;

   }

   [DataContract(Namespace = "DataContracts")]
   public class Bar
   {
       [DataMember]
       public string First;

       [DataMember]
       public string Second;

       [DataMember]
       public Foo[] ManyFoos;
   }

   [DataContract(Namespace = "DataContracts")]
   public class Root
   {
       [DataMember]
       public string First;

       [DataMember]
       public string Second;

       [DataMember]
       public Bar[] ManyBars;
   }
   ```
2. Use the DataContractSerializer to transform your object graph into an XML document.

   ```
   var root = new Root()
   {
       ... snip, object initialization ...
   };

   var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Root));
   var xmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(xmlStringBuilder, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }))
   {
       serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, root);
   }

   var xmlString = xmlStringBuilder.ToString();
   ```

This produces the following XML (for my example anyway).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="DataContracts">
  <First>Root01_First</First>
  <ManyBars>
    <Bar>
      <First>Bar01_First</First>
      <ManyFoos>
        <Foo>
          <First>Foo01_First</First>
          <Second>Foo01_Second</Second>
          <Third>Foo01_Third</Third>
        </Foo>
        <Foo>
          <First>Foo02_First</First>
          <Second>Foo02_Second</Second>
          <Third>Foo02_Third</Third>
        </Foo>
      </ManyFoos>
      <Second>Bar01_Second</Second>
    </Bar>
    <Bar>
      <First>Bar02_First</First>
      <ManyFoos>
        <Foo>
          <First>Foo03_First</First>
          <Second>Foo03_Second</Second>
          <Third>Foo03_Third</Third>
        </Foo>
      </ManyFoos>
      <Second>Bar02_Second</Second>
    </Bar>
  </ManyBars>
  <Second>Root01_Second</Second>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this will help me alot ... I wasnt sure where to start digging.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/mark as the answer if it helped you/answered your question. That's how the Stack Overflow system works.