# How to read same child element types from an XML tree recursively?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have a sample xml file in following format:-

[image]
Also, I have a Control class shown below:

```
 class Control 
 {
    private string id;
    public string Id
    {
      get { return id; }
      set { id = value; }
    }


    private string controlType;
    public string ControlType
    {
      get { return controlType; }
      set { controlType = value; }
    }

    private string searchProperties;
    public string SearchProperties
    {
      get { return searchProperties; }
      set { searchProperties = value; }
    }

    public List<Control> ChildrenControl = new List<Control>();
  }
```

I need to read the XML file mentioned above and populate the code. I am not sure how to recursively do that. I was thinking to use Linq to XML, but not sure how to use it recursively in this case in which parent and child elements are of the same type. Can someone please help me with this problem?

Thanks,
Harit

Comment: Don't post pictures of code... Put the XML within your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Try the following. It uses Linq to XML and a recursive function to parse the controls from out of the XML document. It assumes the existence of your XML data in a file called "Controls.xml", and obviously your Control class. Its not the greatest of code, but it should get you started.

```
private void ParseControlsData()
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load("Controls.xml");

    var controls = from control in doc.Element("controls").Elements("control")
                   select CreateFromXElement(control);

    var controlsList = controls.ToList();

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private Control CreateFromXElement(XElement element)
{
    var control = new Control()
    {
        Id = (string)element.Attribute("id"),
        ControlType = (string)element.Attribute("controlType"),
        SearchProperties = (string)element.Attribute("searchProperties")
    };

    var childrenElements = element.Element("childControls");
    if (childrenElements != null)
    {
        var children = from child in childrenElements.Elements("control")
                       select CreateFromXElement(child);

        control.ChildrenControl = children.ToList();
    }

    return control;
}
```

Notes:

- In the ParseControlsData function, it uses query expression syntax to select the first element in the document called "controls" (your root), and then selects all sub-elements named "control". A very similar expression occurs inside the CreateFromXElement function, except it needs to find an element called "childControls".
- There's no real error checking. You'll definitely need some.

**Update:**

Don't do this, it doesn't work for your example because you have values stored in attributes, and by default the DataContractSerializer + DataContractAttributes combination does not support that (without a whole bunch of extra work). Other options are Linq to XML (as you suggested) and using the XmlSerializer (which is similar to the DataContractSerializer, but uses its own set of attributes). I'll look into it further.

**Previous Answer:**

One way to turn an XML document into an Object Graph is to mark the classes you want to create from the XML with DataContract attributes, and to use the DataContractSerializer. All you need to do is make sure that the DataContract(Name = "X") and DataMember(Name = "Y") match the names of the elements inside your XML.

Have a look at my answer on [XML Element Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276774/xml-element-selection/20277220#20277220), which is performing the operation you want (taking existing XML and turning it into an Object Graph). You probably wont need to worry about the CDATA stuff that that user ran into, so your solution will probably be a bit simpler.

Also, have a look at my answer on [How to catch/send XML doc with various sub arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230735/how-to-catch-send-xml-doc-with-various-sub-arrays/20231029#20231029), which is performing the reverse operation (that user wanted to create XML from an Object Graph).

*If you can't tell, I'm a fan of the DataContractSerializer :)*

Comment: Your final answere works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion using `Func<>` delegate, but you have to declare it before specifying the actual delegate logic:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.xml");

Func<XElement, List<Control>> childControlsQuery = null;
childControlsQuery =
    x => (from c in x.Elements("control")
          select new Control
          {
              Id = (string)c.Attribute("id"),
              ControlType = (string)c.Attribute("controltype"),
              SearchProperties = (string)c.Attribute("searchproperties"),
              ChildrenControl = childControlsQuery(c.Element("childControls") ?? new XElement("childControls"))
          }).ToList();

var controls = childControlsQuery(xDoc.Root);
```

You can remove `?? new XElement("childControls")` if you're sure there is always `childControls` element, even when given control does not have any childs.

And if you're sure there is always only one main control, you can get it as:

```
var mainControl = controls.First();
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works for me att. Thank you for your help and time. :)